# Weird thing and need help-After installing Ubuntu, can't see C drive from Ubuntu, and D drive are no longer appered in Windows

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning, hard-drive

So I installed Ubuntu on a computer, now when I login to Ubuntu, I can see my D drive but not C. here a picture from Ubuntu, the upper drive is D:
[image]

But, throw Win7 it's different-The opposite. i can see C drive but D have disappeared (i could see it before and there are some study files of mine)

Thanks!

Comment: Can we please see the output of the following command: `sudo fdisk -l`. Also, when you installed Ubuntu, what option did you choose at the partitioning screen?

Answer (score 1):

Where C: went

Type this command in a terminal window

```
df -h
```

this will list all the mounted partitions and their stats in human readable format.
Look for any partitions either by size or by the "Mounted on" column that matches your "C: drive"

Take note of the size and partition number of the "D: Drive" that you can not access in windows

sda = 1st hardrive
sdb = 2nd hardrive
etc.
sda1 = 1st partition on 1st harddrive
sda2 = 2nd partition on 1st harddrive
etc.

Where D: went

In Windows click Start -> then right click on Computer -> click on Manage -> Disk Management

Here you should see any detected drives you have on your system and the partitions that are on them. You will want to leave any partition that say unknown alone as this is where Ubuntu lies. Look for any NTFS partitions that are not labeled (C:), this is most likely you missing drive. Right click on the NTFS partition and choose "Mark Partition as active". Read any warning that may appear (just in case). The drive should be given a drive letter and should then show up under Computer as expected.

Comment: The user has mentioned that he can see the Drive D from ubuntu which means that it can be seen as an external drive as also visible from the pic.The visible drive cannot be C because the OP has stated so. And if Ubuntu was installed on drive D, it would not be visible from Ubuntu as an external drive either.

Comment: You're right, I miss read the post I'll update the answer. Good catch

Comment: :) do delete this answer

Comment: thank everyone i solved the problem by installing "beside windows" (sorry for doing it wrong with the partitions), thank you very much for helping and giving answers, i'm very approciated it. Thanks!